# I need 2 Authorize.net accounts to be credited while making a single payment

Tags: authorize.net

I'm developing a B2C site where many shop enroll with the site and sell their products. The Site owner needs to get a 5% of the sales done through their site from the sellers. That is when a customer buys product for $100, $5 must be credited to the site owner's Authorize.net account and 95$ must be credited to Seller's Authorize.net account. Does Authorize.net has this option already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you [*can't do it*](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Multiple-Payees-for-single-Credit-Card-Transaction/td-p/3629) with Auth.NET

The good news are that you CAN implement such a behavior with [*other*](http://www.bluesnap.com/) payment processing solutions - by taking advantage of their affiliation system.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Paypal for achieving this task.

Comment: Hi, Yes. I need both the methods to be implemented. Paypal and Authorize.net.